# Copy from one workbook to another with checking cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy some data from one workbook to another, with checking certain cells content from 2 files. Below is my code:

```
    Sub GetFileCopyData()
   Dim Fname As String
   Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
   Dim DestWbk As Workbook
   Dim miesiac() As Variant
   Dim m_i, i, wiersz_nazw As Integer
   Dim Msc, nazw As String

   miesiac = Array(styczeń, luty, marzec, kwiecień, maj, czerwiec, lipiec, sierpień, wrzesień, październik, listopad, grudzień)

   Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook
   Set SrcWbk = ActiveWorkbook
   Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
   If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
   Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)
   Set DestWbk = ActiveWorkbook


   Msc = SrcWbk.Cells(2, 13).Text
   m_i = szukaj(miesiac, Msc)


   nazw = Cells(3, 4).Text
   For i = 1 To 100 Step 1
        If nazw Like "*" & SrcWbk.Cells(i, 24) & "*" Then
            wiersz_nazw = i: Exit For
        End If
   Next

   SrcWbk.Cells(wiersz_nazw, 2).Copy DestWbk.Cells(m_i + 7, 3)

End Sub

Function szukaj(ByRef lista As Variant, ByVal wartosc As String)
  Dim found As Integer, foundi As Integer ' put only once
  found = -1
  For foundi = LBound(lista) To UBound(lista):
   'If lista(foundi) = wartosc   Then
   If StrComp(lista(foundi), wartosc, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    found = foundi: Exit For
   End If
  Next
  szukaj = found
End Function
```

It gets runtime 438 error in this line:

```
Msc = SrcWbk.Cells(2, 13).Text
```

The script have to get text parameter from source workbook cell 2,13, then take number for this text from array. Then scrip has to get text parameter from destination work book cell 3,4 and search for it in source workbook. Then I can copy some data.

Comment: `Cells` is a property of the worksheet, not the workbook.

Comment: Btw I think your function can be replaced with MATCH.

Comment: So I need to use it like `SrcWbk.Worksheets.cells`? My szukaj function can be replaced by match?

Comment: Yes, `SrcWbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,2)`. Your function appears to be returning the position of a value in an array?

Comment: The function is supposted to work with multiple files, and in some files, worksheets can have different name, but there is always just one sheet in workbook. Yes, the function returns the possiton of an array. `m_i = Application.Match(Msc, miesiac,0)`?

Comment: "So I need to use it like SrcWbk.Worksheets.cells?" At a high level, yes.  You need to identify the worksheet.  You can do it by index `SrcWbk.Worksheets(1).Cells` or the worksheet name `SrcWbk.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells` or if the worksheet is in `ThisWorkbook` by using a codename`Sheet1.Cells`

Comment: What the strings when you define `miesiac` do they mean? If they are really strings, they must be between double quotes `miesiac = Array("styczeń", "luty", ...)`. If they are variable keeping God knows what, you must show us what they really are...

Comment: Just use the index then as per @ProfoundlyOblivious's comment. Yes re the match, declare `m_i` as variant and check if it's a number (otherwise there is no match). I think your `i` loop could also be replaced with `Match` or `Find`.

Comment: Also aren't you setting `SrcWbk` and `DestWbk` as the same?

Comment: Okay. So far everything works. @SJR, I dont get it, the last comment. One more thing. If I had to change my szukaj function to search for partial text like: `If wartosc Like "*" & lista(foundi) & "*" Then` can I still use match for that?

Comment: You have this line `Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)` and the following line is `Set DestWbk = ActiveWorkbook` but when you open a workbook it becomes the active workbook. I'll post an answer shortly which may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This covers most of the comments. I think it should work, but you might have to check the workbook/sheet names as I wasn't entirely clear in all cases.

And check I have the `wiersz_nazw` bit correct.

The original 438 error was caused because `Cells` needs a sheet parent, not a workbook parent.

```
Sub GetFileCopyData()

Dim Fname As String
Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
Dim DestWbk As Workbook
Dim miesiac() As Variant
Dim m_i As Variant, i As Long, wiersz_nazw As Variant
Dim Msc As String, nazw As String 'each one needs to be specified

miesiac = Array(styczen, luty, marzec, kwiecien, maj, czerwiec, lipiec, sierpien, wrzesien, pazdziernik, listopad, grudzien)

Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook 'file containing code
Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)

Msc = SrcWbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 13).Text
m_i = Application.Match(Msc, miesiac, 0)

If Not IsNumeric(m_i) Then m_i = -1
nazw = SrcWbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 4).Text 'change workbook/sheet as necessary
wiersz_nazw = Application.Match("*" & nazw & "*", SrcWbk.Worksheets(1).Range("X1:X100"), 0)
If IsNumeric(wiersz_nazw) Then
    SrcWbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(wiersz_nazw, 2).Copy DestWbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(m_i + 7, 3) 'change sheets as necessary
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfect. Now it's just one problem with line: `m_i = Application.Match(Msc, miesiac, 0)` Msc is string consisting of couple words eg. its styczen month. Match returns error.

Comment: Glad to hear it. OK so you mean it's not found in `miesiac`? In your original function you set its value to -1 if not found. Could do the same here?

Comment: Propably yes, coz in orginal function it wasnt fixed yet

Comment: I've made a small change above.

Comment: m_i is stil error 2042. As I said, Msc consist of couple words eg. month styczeń. It's unable to match it to miesiac array where values are "styczeń", "luty" etc.

Comment: Shouldn’t matter should be set to -1 if not found. Have you stepped through?

Comment: But it has to be found. I need match for m_i to line: `SrcWbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(wiersz_nazw, 2).Copy DestWbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(m_i + 7, 3) 'change sheets as necessary`.  Line: `m_i = Application.Match(Msc, miesiac, 0) ` has to check the number in array for msc. So if msc is month styczeń, it needs to be matched with "styczeń" from array and return 0

Comment: (1) If it's not found, it's not found. Unless they're variables, your array elements need to be in quotes `Array("styczeń", "luty", ...)` (2) If that's not the problem, I suggest asking a new question as this one was about the 438 error which is solved.

Comment: The 438 is solved, indeed. In my code elements are in quotes. Just if msc = "month styczeń", `m_i = Application.Match(Msc, miesiac, 0)` m_i = error 2042.

Comment: Ah, some light is dawning. So you want to match "month styczeń" with "styczeń"? In that case I think you will need a loop. You could reinstate your function, but if you get stuck I would suggest posting a new question.

Comment: Yeah. With szukaj function it worked fine, but I was wondering if its possible to use match for that :)

Comment: Don't think so because you can't apply wildcards to a whole array.